# Plotting two variables for comparison

Tags: r, plot

I have two variables and I want two compare the values to each other within one plot. For example:

```
v1 = c(0,2,3,4)
v2 = c(3,4,5,6)
```

Now I want a plot with 1 to 4 on the x-axis (because of 4 values for each variable) and 0 to 6 on the y-axis (because 6 is the maximum value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only supply one variable, then `plot` assumes this to be the `y` levels and adds an index to the x-axis. defining the y-limits (`ylim`), one can make sure that both of your series are fully represented on the plot. Here you can use a high level plotting command (`plot`) to plot the first vseries, and then add a low-level plotting command (`points`) to add the second series:

```
v1 = c(0,2,3,4)
v2 = c(3,4,5,6)
ylim <- range(c(v1, v2))
plot(v1, ylim=ylim, col=1, ylab="")
points(v2, col=2)
```